# CDRoom won't mount DVD RW after burning OS to DVD using brasero

Tags: bootable, brasero

I burned a debian distro to a DVD RW and the DVD won't boot to install the distro, if I insert the disc while on OS, the cdrom won't mount. Also if I open gparted it stays "scanning all devices..." forever.

I've also noticed that the were mounted 3 discs or partions after burning the disc.

update: if i run `sudo mount /dev/sr0` the terminal stays waiting forever

update: it shows this mounted discs or partitions but the cdrom/optical drive can't mount the dvd nor can be detected

[image]

Comment: This is a burning DVD issue, so, not really a duplicate

Comment: @IporSircer please don't use that question as a dupe target just because the OP mentions Kali! That question should either _never_ be used as a dupe target (but only as something to point people to) or, if you must use it, only use it as a dupe target if the question is clearly about someone trying to use Kali as a regular OS without the required knowledge.

Comment: If this is about burning a Kali CD, please edit and make that clear. Different distributions have different installation approaches, so Debian might work while Kali won't, or Kali might work and Ubuntu won't etc. So if this is about Kali, let us know. Also, clarify exactly what you burned, where you got it from and how you burned it.

Comment: Finally, I strongly urge you to have a look at the [Why is Kali hard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) post. If you are having trouble with creating an installation CD, and you don't know what those mounted disks are, Kali is probably not the right place to start. There's no reason why you should know any of this, of course, but Kali is a tool designed for experts and is not easy to use for non-experts, and this question suggests you aren't an expert.

Answer (score 0):

### Question for @Rui F Ribeiro, I see that you are an expert formatter. Do you have any useful guides or links for proper post formatting?

[1] - Verify your boot order in your BIOS to make sure your DVD drive is before your harddisk.

To do so;

- When cpu starts type F-12 or f10 to launch BIOS set -up.
- If you search bios boot for your computer hardware you will find the
  shortcut key.

if that does not work

[2] - Try to create a second live cd with a different application, k3b, gnome-disk-utlitity etc

and before you install again

[3] - Check your checksum on your dvd disk to make sure file is not corrupted

Comment: I've done step 1, the cdroom starts to read the DVD for about 20 seconds and then stops and proceeds to boot main OS...  I can't acess DVD, it won't mount

Comment: If your system is booting the main OS after reading the DVD for like 10-20 seconds. It means there is an issue with the ISO format itself.

Probably during install, you need to restart the install and please try to use k3b. It is my fav for dvds!

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a try. I post results soon. But there is a problem, the dvd wont won't mount... Even brasero can't detect it... when I open gparted it stays on "scanning all devices..." forever (or until Iremove the dvd)

Comment: Yep, even k3b can't detect the DVD because it wont mount

Comment: @OrdnaelSusej have you tried burning a new CD? That's the first easy step.

Comment: @OrdnaelSusej If you are really having problems, I can remote with you.

Comment: I only have  this dvd hehehe

Comment: lol that is your problem. Do you have a 4gig usb key that you can use? Or a new DVD?